# Xcode Build Error "missing value detected"

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

I made an App for iPhone. Until some days ago everything went fine with testing it on my iPhone. But since a few days I get an error when I want to build and run the App on the phone.

I get the error: `A missing value was detected.`

[image]

Where do I find a possible solution for this problem? Which entries do I need to check?

Comment: Try cleaning the project, restarting xcode and rebuilding. U don't provide enough info on what changed so that we can help more

Comment: Run `security find-identity` from the command line and check if that SHA-1 (starting `0A8A84...`) appears in the list of valid identities.  You will probably have to do `security unlock-keychain` first.

Comment: @trojanfoe I get 0 identities found

Comment: Then you don't have the correct certs etc installed.  In Xcode 5, go to `Preferences > Accounts` and do a refresh and that should install that gumpf.

Comment: Well, I now did that about 100 times in the past 2 days. I already deleted all iOS Certificates and made new once...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear out all certificates on Keychain as well as on developer.apple.com

Then set them new and make sure that you set the right bundle identifier (has to match!).